# React Native component for Google Cloud Vision API - Text Detection

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-vision

I am using React Native's Image Picker component to capture images on my app. Before showing the picture I want to parse it using Google Cloud Vision's Text Detection API. I've been searching on components in React Native but no result. Does anybody know if there is something around or if it can be done within React Native?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cloud-vision-api. Looks like it should do the job.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Given that the answer is a node module there's not much else useful that I can say.

Comment: In such occurrences, one must ask if the question is in fact on topic since asking for recommendations is likely going to get a question closed.